# Laravel Query Relationship Constraints - Inject Variable

Tags: laravel

this should be an easy question. I am trying to query my Post model to find all posts that have a certain topic. Below is the controller method.

```
// Get collection of posts with this topic

    // Get specific topic for this page
    $postTopic = Topic::where('topic_name', $topic)->first();

    $posts = Post::whereHas('topic', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('topic_id', $postTopic->id);
    })->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

I am struggling with how to define the $postTopic variable. Thank you!

Comment: `function (Builder $query) use ($postTopic)`; if you don't pass `$postTopic` into the scope of your subquery, it won't be available. Does that solve your issue? You didn't really specify what error you're getting.

Comment: You got it, that's what I was looking for. I'm happy to choose your answer if you want to post it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial approach is close, but the tricky thing about anonymous functions is "scope", where variables, unless explicitly passed into the scope, are not available. For example:

```php
$postTopic = Topic::where('topic_name', $topic)->first();

$posts = Post::whereHas('topic', function (Builder $query) {
  $query->where('topic_id', $postTopic->id);
})->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

While this code looks correct, since you're not passing `$postTopic` into `function (Builder $query)`, you'll receive the error:

> Undefined variable `$postTopic` ...

To resolve this, you need to use a `use()` clause:

```php
$postTopic = Topic::where('topic_name', $topic)->first();

$posts = Post::whereHas('topic', function (Builder $query) use ($postTopic) {
  $query->where('topic_id', $postTopic->id);
})->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Any number of variables can be passed and referenced in scope using `use()`, and you should no longer get the undefined variable error.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. I was searching the docs, but didn’t see this in the section covering Eloquent Relationships.